# Editing anchor position in header of Microsoft Word using vba

Tags: vba, ms-word, anchor, word-2010

I am working on a VBA macro, which I wrote only parts of it myself, for MS-Word that changes the orientation of the page and then copies the header and footer of previous pages to the new page and some other stuff:

```
Selection.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
ActiveDocument.Sections.Last.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False

ActiveDocument.Sections(ActiveDocument.Sections.Last.index - 1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Select
Selection.Copy

ActiveDocument.Sections.Last.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Select
Selection.Paste

ActiveDocument.Sections.Last.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
ActiveDocument.Sections.Last.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False

formatHeader wdHeaderFooterPrimary
formatHeader wdHeaderFooterFirstPage
```

There is a text in a TextBox which is anchored to header. What I want to do now is to change its position on the pages with "Landscape" orientation.

How can I change the layout options (see images below)? I haven't been able to find any information.

This is how my document looks like after changing the page orientation to "Landscape":
[image]

As you see, the paragraph on the side, in the TextBox is not in the middle. so I want to move it a bit higher. You can also see the anchor in this image.
[image]

This is how I did it in Word as a user:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to set where the measurement should be taken from (`RelativeHorizontalPosition`) and then use the Shape's `Left` setting. Relative to pretty much anything except `wdCharacter` the horizontal position will be static on the page when the text is edited; vertically, `wdLine` and `wdParagraph` would be equivalent to using "Move with text".

I've streamlined the code you posted somewhat by declaring and using objects for the last Section and the Shape.

Instead of copying and pasting, this code uses `Range.FormattedText` to copy-transfer the content from one header to another. This is preferable to using the Clipboard for those situations where it works (between any two Word Ranges).

```
Dim secLast as Word.Section
Dim shp as Word.Shape

Set secLast = ActiveDocument.Sections.Last
secLast.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
secLast.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
secLast.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.FormattedText = _
  ActiveDocument.Sections(secLast.index - 1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.FormattedText

secLast.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
secLast.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False

formatHeader wdHeaderFooterPrimary
formatHeader wdHeaderFooterFirstPage

Set shp = secLast.Range.Shapes(1)
shp.RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage 
shp.Left = 33 ' Or you can use, for example CentimetersToPoints(1.4)
shp.RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
shp.Top = CentimetersToPoints(14)
```